# How do I make a Dialog Fragment's background invisible?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I used youtuber Coding in Flow's method to create a custom dialog. I've been trying all day to make the dialog's background transparent. I've used every single method I've found online. Non worked.

Here's how it goes:

- First here's the Dialog layout **layout_dialog.xml** :

  ```
  <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
          android:background="@drawable/dialog_background">

          <!-- The contents of the Dialog go here -->

      </RelativeLayout>

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/iconImageView2"
          android:layout_width="100dp"
          android:layout_height="100dp"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
          android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          app:srcCompat="@android:mipmap/sym_def_app_icon" />

  </RelativeLayout>
  ```
- Here's the Dialog class:

  ```
   public class DialogBrightness extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

       //declare whatever variables here

       @Override
       public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

           LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);

           builder.setView(view)
                   .setTitle("Login")
                   .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                       }
                   })
                   .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                           //get whatever values
                           listener.apply(//values);
                       }
                   });

           //findViewById for your dialog contents here

           return builder.create();
       }

       public interface DialogBrightnessListener {
           void apply(//values);
       }
   }
  ```
- And here's the Dialog being called from the Main activity:

  ```
  DialogBrightness dialogBrightness = new DialogBrightness();
  dialogBrightness.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Brightness Dialog");
  ```

This is how the Dialog appears:

[image]

I'm trying to make the top white part invisible. Nothing works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can design the layout like following. There is an extra layout, but in case of dialogs, it will help

[image]

Comment: Is setting it invisible in the layout the same as setting it invisible after `builder.create();` where I use `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResouce(android.R.color.transparent);`?

Comment: You can set the transparent color in XML layout. It is easier. Setting the color from code may cause error if it is not properly called.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

put the code below in the onCreateDialog:

```
    // set the dialog background to transparent
    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    // remove background dim 
    getDialog().getWindow().setDimAmount(0);
```

Comment: If I write this in main activity after creating the dialog, it returns null and app crashes.

Comment: or in onStart()

Comment: The problem was that I was putting it before the `builder.create()` call, which is why it was returning null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

set the background color of the parent layout to:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background">

    <!-- The contents of the Dialog go here -->

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iconImageView2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@android:mipmap/sym_def_app_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried that already :(. It just comes up white, not transparent.

Comment: What other ways are there?

Comment: did you try setting the background programmatically?

Comment: It seems to give Null exception or something

Comment: and you can try the second answer

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong :). I replaced `return builder.create();` with `Dialog dialog = builder.create();` then after that statement `dialog.getWindow()` no longer returned null, and finally finish with just `return dialog;`

Comment: But now I have another problem. after writing `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));` the dialog's width now takes up the whole phone. Plus the bottom of the dialog (where SAVE and CANCEL buttons are) is invisible.

Comment: can you post the screenshot of the result?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219049/discussion-between-afhamu-and-user104163).

Comment: Hey can we talk? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222813/room-for-user104163-and-afhamu